# which valve fitting / adapter combination can i use to connect my kitchen faucet and undersink water filter to my cold water line?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, pipe-fitting

I purchased an underink water filter:
KOHLER Aquifer Under-Sink Double Cartridge Water Filtration System

I was using the plastic connection that came with it:

[image]

Connected like so:
[image]

The top connects to my faucet (plastic male to female connection), and the blue plastic hose push connects to the KOHLER water filter which connects to my fridge's water line

The fitting is leaking where it threads into the water valve (plastic female to male connection). I took the fitting to lowes/home depot and tried to attach it to newer valves but it would always spin in place when trying to connect. I suppose the threads got damaged.

Please, **how can I combine a brass fitting to replace this setup?** I don't mind having to use several adapters

In the photographs of the water filter I noticed they used an adapter as well:

[image]

The closest thing I could find in lowes was a male to push adapter:
[image]

This is my water valve after some disconnections:
[image]

I am **pretty sure its 3/4 inch for all connections** (this may be incorrect according to manual stating 3/8 inch water supply connection.

The **OD of the blue plastic tube is 3/4** though **the push connection is labled 3/8**.
Could you please point me to the parts I need to fix this issue? I currently have turned off my cold water supply because the leak is really bad.

Thank you

Comment: this is a compression fitting

Comment: The push-connect fitting is going to be the problem here. Can you please measure and report the **OD** (outside diameter) of the blue plastic tubing, in inches?

Comment: @JimmyFix-it
Okay, the **OD** of the blue plastic tubing is **3/4 inches.**



the manual says: 
This system connects to a 3/8″ (9/16″-24 UNEF-2A) compression
connection. Special fittings may need to be purchased to
accommodate other connections

Comment: I couldn't edit my comment above. I measured by placing the tube on measuring tape. However 3/4inch seems wrong for an OD because that black reducing coupler in the photograph is a 3/8inch OD to 1/4inch OD (assuming the amazon description is 100% accurate here) So that means the blue plastic tube is actually 3/8? Sorry

Comment: Kohler's service website: https://www.kohler.com/en/products/water-filtration/shop-water-filtration/aquifer-double-cartridge-water-filtration-system-77686. They sell a brass tee for 14 USD: https://www.kohler.com/en/support/find-a-service-part/shop-parts/tee-brass-3-8-compression-1285417?skuId=1285417. Typically I try to avoid mating female plastic threads to male metal threads, as I always break something. So I like your male threaded connector (as long as it actually fits your hose).

Comment: Does your new connector have tapered threads? It would say something like "NPT," "M-NPT," or "MIP," although it might say nothing at all. Chances are that they're tapered threads, so you would want a tee with 3/8" compression X 3/8" compression X 3/8" FIP. I can't find such a fitting, so you're probably stuck with 3/8" compression X 3/8" compression X 3/8" MIP and a 3/8" FIP X 3/8" FIP adapter.

Comment: @popham the brass tee for 14 USD link doesnt work for me, the product cannot be found. im not sure if the male thread is tapered, i don't have it on me right now to check. if you prefer the male plastic to female metal which Tee could i purchase? i haven't seen a tee adapter that has two female compressions and 1 male. thank you

Comment: @user2285215, their website is too expensive anyway, so don't worry about it. You want a 3/8" female compression X 3/8" male compression X 3/8" male iron pipe (MIP) tee. Then a 3/8" female iron pipe (FIP) X 3/8" female iron pipe (FIP) adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using an adapter tee:
[image]

and a 3/8 Inch Compression Female Connector to Push to Connect
[image]

Thanks everyone